# Flutter stack z-index Positioned

Tags: flutter

Expected :

[image]

What I get :

[image]

i want to move the **Positioned** widget outside the stack ,

(in CSS we use Z-index, how to do it in flutter ? )

code :

```
 Column( Expanded(
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                   .........
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: -30, <-- here
                    right: 60,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                      radius: 30,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.favorite,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                 ),

  ...........
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with **clipBehavior: Clip.none,**

```
Stack(
   clipBehavior: Clip.none,
...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Please add  clipBehavior: Clip.none,


 Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                children: [
                  Container(
                   .........
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: -30, <-- here
                    right: 60,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                      radius: 30,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.favorite,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                 )
```